# Displaying Labes Vertically above bar in bar graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am working with someone's report and currently they have the data labels showing within the bar, most of the time this is ok except when the figures are bigger than the bar and it causes the problem shown below.  What I want to do is display the lables vertically at the top but outside of each bar but I cant seem to make that happen, can anyone suggest how this is done.

Thanks P

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working in an example chart by setting the following properties:

[image]

Go to the **Chart Series Properties** by either clicking on the chart labels or the data field in the Designer.

Gave results:

[image]

This looks like what you're after. However, in my experience SSRS is pretty poor at being smart with labels, so even if you've set up everything correctly the chart may still look poor and you'll need to try tweaking it further (chart size, max value in axis, etc).

Comment: Hi Ian,  Thanks for the detailed help yet again and yes that is spot on what I am after, I have checked and unfortunately I already have those options set so no sure why they are still showing as they are?  Any other thoughts?  Thanks P

Comment: Hmm, you're probably thinking the same as me, i.e. something else is affecting it, then. As you can see, I just threw a quick chart together and it happened to work, so the only thing I can really suggest is to start from scratch and see if it works on a new basic chart with your data, then if/when it's working keep adding back formatting, etc, until it matches the old chart. Not amazing advice, I admit, but all I can really think of.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks again for coming back to me on this and I was getting to the point where I thought there must be something else going on.  Unfortunately there are that many other things going on in these reports it would take me a considerable length of time to work out what else I would need to do, they have had these reports like this for some time and will have to remain in such a way until I can find a work around :-) thanks again for the help, very much appreciated. P